# Reading JSON object with JSONArray inside to RDD using Scala and without using Dataframe

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark, rdd, json

I was able to read a json object to RDD using the following code without using dataframe, here is my JSON Object:

```
{"first":"John","last":"Smith","address":{"line1":"1 main street","city":"San Francisco","state":"CA","zip":"94101"}}
```

Here is the code for reading it to RDD:

```
package com.spnotes.spark
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.typesafe.scalalogging.Logger
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext,SparkConf}
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
class Person {
    @JsonProperty var first:String=null
    @JsonProperty var last:String=null
    @JsonProperty var address:Address=null
    override def toString=s"Person(first=$first, last=$last, address=$address)"
}

class Address {
    @JsonProperty var line1:String=null
    @JsonProperty var line2:String=null
    @JsonProperty var city:String=null
    @JsonProperty var state:String=null
    @JsonProperty var zip:String=null
    override def toString=s"Address(line1=$line1, line2=$line2, city=$city, state=$state, zip=$zip)"
}

object JSONFileReaderWriter{
    // val logger =     Logger(LoggerFactory.getLogger("JSONFileReaderWriter"))
    val mapper = new ObjectMapper()

    def main(argv: Array[String]): Unit = {

    if (argv.length != 2) {
        println("Please provide 2 parameters <inputfile> <outputfile>")
        System.exit(1)
    }
    val inputFile = argv(0)
    val outputFile = argv(1)

    println(inputFile)
    println(outputFile)

    //logger.debug(s"Read json from $inputFile and write to $outputFile")

    val sparkConf = new   SparkConf().setMaster("local[1]").setAppName("JSONFileReaderWriter")
    val sparkContext = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
    val errorRecords = sparkContext.accumulator(0)
    val records = sparkContext.textFile(inputFile)

    var results = records.flatMap { record =>
        try {
            Some(mapper.readValue(record, classOf[Person]))
        } catch {
            case e: Exception => {
            errorRecords += 1
            None
        }
     }
   }//.filter(person => person.address.city.equals("mumbai"))

   results.saveAsTextFile(outputFile)

println("Number of bad records " + errorRecords)
   }
}
```

But when there is a JSONArray inside the JSONObject, I could not figure it out how to extend the code. Any help is really appreciated.

Here is the JSONObject that I want to read to RDD without using dataframe:

```
{"first":"John","last":"Smith","address":[{"line1":"1 main street","city":"San Francisco","state":"CA","zip":"94101"},{"line1":"2 main street","city":"Palo Alto","state":"CA","zip":"94305"}]}
```

I DO NOT want to use Spark SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to this problem. This is the updated JSON Objects:

```
{"first":"John","last":"Smith","address":[{"line1":"1 main street","city":"San Francisco","state":"CA","zip":"94101"},{"line1":"1 main street","city":"sunnyvale","state":"CA","zip":"94000"}]}
{"first":"Tim","last":"Williams","address":[{"line1":"1 main street","city":"Mountain View","state":"CA","zip":"94300"},{"line1":"1 main street","city":"San Jose","state":"CA","zip":"92000"}]}
```

Here is the code:

```
package com.myspark.spark
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._
import org.json4s.jackson.Serialization
import org.json4s.jackson.Serialization.{read, write}
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}

case class Person (first: String,last: String, address: List[Address]){
  override def toString = s"Person(first=$first, last=$last, address=$address)"
}
case class Address ( line1: String , city: String, state: String, zip: String){
  override def toString = s"Address(line1=$line1, city=$city, state=$state, zip=$zip)"
}

object JSONFileReaderWriter {
    def main(argv: Array[String]): Unit = {

        if (argv.length != 2) {
            println("Please provide 2 parameters <inputfile> <outputfile>")
            System.exit(1)
        }
        val inputFile = argv(0)
        val outputFile = argv(1)
        val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[1]").setAppName("JSONFileReaderWriter")
        val sparkContext = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
        val errorRecords = sparkContext.accumulator(0)
        val records = sparkContext.textFile(inputFile)

        val dataObjsRDD = records.map { myrecord =>
            implicit val formats = DefaultFormats // Workaround as      DefaultFormats is not serializable
            val jsonObj = parse(myrecord)
            val addresses= jsonObj \ "address"
            println((addresses(0) \ "city").extract[String])
            jsonObj.extract[Person]
        }

        dataObjsRDD.saveAsTextFile(outputFile)
  }
}
```

Here is the build.sbt file:

```
name := "JSONFileReaderWriter"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.5.2"

libraryDependencies += "org.json4s" %% "json4s-jackson" % "3.2.11"
```

I used the following to run the code on my local machine:

```
spark-submit  --master local[1] target/scala-2.11/jsonfilereaderwriter_2.11-1.0.jar input/inputarray.json output
```

The inputarray.json contains the JSON Objects that is mentioned on top of this post. After you run the code, you should expect to see the following outputs:

```
San Francisco
Mountain View
```

I used json4s to read the file. Hopefully it helps the rest who have the same problem.